# CORS: Apache gives 404 on preflight OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, apache, google-chrome, cors, basic-authentication

I'm trying to do a Basic HTTP Authentification through XHR client request on another domain but in Chrome, I issue:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://my-remote-domain.com. Response for
>   preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404

The apache server configuration with mod_headers loaded is the following (apache.conf):

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Cache-Control, Host"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
```

I tried with a wildcard `"*"` but Chrome seems to refuse when `Credentials` header is set to true on the client side.

Another solution consisted on using regex for sub-domains, and this works:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^(https?://localhost|https://(.*)+\.domain\.com\.fr)$" ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN=$1
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "%{ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN}e" env=ORIGIN_SUB_DOMAIN
```

But now I'm stuck on the 404 error code on Pre-flight OPTIONS response.

Even when forcing Apache to return 200 on HTTP OPTIONS method calls with the following, I still have a 404:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

JavaScript code:

```
function connect(login, passwd){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", 'https://my-remote-domain.com', true);
    xhr.withCredentials = true;
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", 'Basic ' + btoa(login + ':' + passwd));
    xhr.onload = function () {
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Note: When lauching chrome with `chrome.exe --disable-web-security --user-data-dir` for tests, it works correctly.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does it work when you remove the need for basic auth?

Comment: Yes I obtain 200 OK and 401 when removing credential from xhr call.

Comment: have you try to add Authorization in Access-Control-Allow-Headers